# extracting song info from EXTINF from live radio stream

Tags: http, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Is it possible to extract the song info from a live HLS M3U8 radio stream using for example python or any other program?

I can currently view the song info by opening the response in Google DevTools, but I'd like to automatically scrape/extract the song title and save it to a file each time the song changes.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Off course that is possible. You have to decide which programming language you're going to use to code it. If you did you can find examples everywhere presumably. And if not you modify a script. If you then hit an error... then comeback and post your question. Now its too vague and too broad.

Comment: I used to scrape streams using python, so I am slightly familiar with python, though I am not good at programming... I had found a script which was ready which uses VLC, but the problem is that VLC is not handling the metadata of the stream mentioned above properly, so I cannot use the script I have.

Comment: if you add the information from which URL you get the stream/metadata and the script you have, implement a try to get/extract that data (i.e. give short metadata example)  I, and possibly many others, might be able to help you out on this. (I too do extract it still manually... so mutual intest in this ;-)

Comment: hm did not quite understand.. i've been hours trying to find something online to guide me. any chance of helping me further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the Python library (https://github.com/globocom/m3u8) to parse and manipulate m3u8 manifests instead of writing your own script. You have to check if it supports the tags you are trying to get metadata for. If not you should be able to easily extend the library to add the functionality you need.

```
import m3u8

def get_movie(line, data, lineno):
    if line.startswith('#MOVIE-NAME:'):
        custom_tag = line.split(':')
        data['movie'] = custom_tag[1].strip()

m3u8_obj = m3u8.load('http://videoserver.com/playlist.m3u8', 
custom_tags_parser=get_movie)
print(m3u8_obj.data['movie'])  #  million dollar baby
```

Comment: I am now managing to run the script and get the song title as a result. But now I wish to go further in order to log the songs. How can I amend the below code to leave the script open, listening to the URL, and each time the song title changes, it writes to a text file. I am trying some things, but it is not working. Thanks!

https://ibb.co/0BvJ8Vr

Comment: @AndrewFabri - Hey, If the url is a stream then you have to constantly request the url to get any new changes happening on the stream. I would suggest you to convert the code to a daemon process that runs every few seconds and checks the stream and write to file if there are any changes.

Comment: @AndrewFabri - Please mark this as valid answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: @AndrewFabri Yes you should be able to do that in windows using python or node.

Comment: Hi Patel, I've managed to do this! I am now struggling with amending the code in order to ONLY print to text file when the song title isn't 'None'. I've attached an image of my code - maybe you could guide me as to how I would add this? https://ibb.co/PjmQb9W

Comment: @AndrewFabri - Why add songTitle to a list and then loop over it? You could just use `if sonTitle is not None: print >> outSong, timestamp, songTitle`

Comment: Wow Okay that worked haha Thanks! I might be asking for much here, but I have one last request if possible... How possible is it to avoid having the same text written several times until the 'song' is not part of the m3u8 string? So basically what happens is that once a song airs, the title for that song remains in the m3u8 tag for around 15/30 seconds, thus that title is printed several times. Is there a way to let python know not to print further until the title changes? Thanks

Comment: https://ibb.co/Y7fsJJ9 - so in this case, I would only need to see the first line of these 2 songs (highlighted in yellow). Thanks

Comment: @AndrewFabri - Keep a list of titles in a variable and add the title to list when it first appear on the playlist then add a check to not add title to file which exists in list when you are looping